# reading cylindrical connector schematic

Tags: connector

The schematic on the side of a Panasonic cassette deck is (-)-(o)-(+) where the brackets are actually a circle.  Does that mean that the negative is the sleeve and the + is the tip?

Comment: Can you post a pictoral, rather than ASCII, version of the schematic?

Answer (score 5):

Here are the commonly used symbols for [jack polarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_symbols) on such devices:

[image: polarity symbols]

If it is the left one, then the sleeve will be negative, if the right the sleeve will be positive.
If you are still not sure, post a picture of your jack, socket and symbol (the model of cassette deck might be helpful too)

Answer (score 3):

If the symbol on your cassette deck is similair to the one in the image then it would mean that the sleeve would be the negative terminal and the tip would be the positive terminal.

[image: Symbol on a 12v 1A DC power supply]